# Upload .xlsx files to express/node and mongoDB

Tags: node.js, excel, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make a web application where a manager can upload a weekly work schedule to the application and then have the application parse out the data into html format.

My question to you guys is how to have the application convert the excel file into JSON while it is being upload.  I'm new so I'm not sure how to simultaneously upload the file to Mongo while converting it to JSON.

edit - in my app.js :

```
  xlsxj = require("xlsx-to-json");
  xlsxj({
    input: "sample.xlsx", 
    output: "output.json"
  }, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });

app.post('/upload' function(req, res) {
  ??? What to put here ???
});
```

my input where the user selects file to upload:

```
  .div(style={position: 'absolute', right: '50px', top: '75px'})
    unless user.email == "cca@gmail.com"
      p Upload New Schedule
      #uploadNew
        form(action="...", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
          input(type="file", name="displayImage")
```

I'm wondering how I go from there to having the input converted to JSON and stored in the DB

Comment: you need to provide extra data. like what packages are you using for handling file uploads. You must first try to code then ask for help if you get any errors.

Comment: @Vishnu I will use package you provided.  Am I correct in the way my app.js is structured with the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xlsxj = require("xlsx-to-json");
app.post('/upload' function(req, res) {
/* upload script here */

  xlsxj({
      input: "sample.xlsx", //change this names based on the upload file name
      output: "output.json"
    }, function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }else {
        console.log(result);
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) to parse the .xlsx file on Node.js.  This is a highly tested library that parses the data into a JSON structure you can iterate over to extract data.  It doesn't parse charts or handle macros but you likely do not need to.

You may or may not choose to store the data in MongoDB.  Mongo is nice for many reasons, but you have to be sure that no attribute has an embedded `$` or `.` as these are reserved and will generate an error.  Another approach you may consider to store the XLSX file or the stringified JSON file on S3, using the [aws-sdk](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several npm packages which can convert xlsx data to json format.
You can search them on [npm website](https://www.npmjs.com/).

Use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-to-json) package.

Once the xlsx file is uploaded to the database. Convert it to xlsx and save it to database.

Comment: thanks, any ideas how could I go from uploading an .xslx file from an input field in html and then using that package to convert to json?

Comment: there will be several examples in the web try to google. see the documentation of the package. You will get some idea.